# Transfer and cleansing data from a html column in SQL Server to other relational table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl, data-cleaning

I have a table with `HTML` data Like below :

```
SELECT 
    [ID],
    [title],
    [authors_html],
    [authors_text]
FROM 
    [wiley].[dbo].[library]
```

Sample of `authors_html` column data :

```
<div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
   <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A" class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a1" data-db-target-for="a1" aria-controls="a1" aria-haspopup="true" id="a1_Ctrl" role="button"><span>M. A. PRICE</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i></a>
   <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content" data-db-target-of="a1" aria-labelledby="a1_Ctrl" role="region" id="a1">
      <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
      <a class="moreInfoLink" href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A">Search for more papers by this author</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
   <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G" class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a2" data-db-target-for="a2" aria-controls="a2" aria-haspopup="true" id="a2_Ctrl" role="button"><span>C. G. ARMSTRONG</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i></a>
   <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content" data-db-target-of="a2" aria-labelledby="a2_Ctrl" role="region" id="a2">
      <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
      <a class="moreInfoLink" href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G">Search for more papers by this author</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to transfer this column data to `Researcher` table :

| ID | Full_Name | Email | Tel | URL | Address | Country | Ostan | University | Madrak | Field | org | Fax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007 | M. A. PRICE | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A | Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K. | U.K. | NULL | The Queen's University of Belfast | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 1008 | C. G. ARMSTRONG | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G | Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K. | U.K. | NULL | The Queen's University of Belfast | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 1009 | B. BOROOMAND | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=BOROOMAND%2C+B | Institute for Numerical Methods in Engineering, University of Wales, Swansea, U.K. | U.K. | University of Wales | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |
| 1010 | O. C. ZIENKIEWICZ | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ZIENKIEWICZ%2C+O+C | Institute for Numerical Methods in Engineering, University of Wales, Swansea, U.K. | U.K. | University of Wales | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |
| 1011 | ZHAO‐PING JIAO | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=JIAO%2C+ZHAO-PING | Department of Civil Engineering, South China Construction University, (West Campus), 510405 Guangzhou, China | China | NULL | South China Construction University | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 1012 | THEODORE H. H. PIAN | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PIAN%2C+THEODORE+H+H | Department of Aeronautics and Astronautics, Massachussets Institute of Technology, Cambridge, MA, U.S.A. | U.S.A. | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |  |
| 1013 | SHENG YONG | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=YONG%2C+SHENG | Department of Modern Mechanics, University of Science and Technology of China, Hei Fei, China | China | University of Science and Technology of China | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |
| 1014 | MIN‐WEI HUANG | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=HUANG%2C+MIN-WEI | Optimal Design Laboratory, College of Engineering, The University of Iowa, Iowa City, IA 52242, U.S.A. | U.S.A. | Iowa | The University of Iowa | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 1015 | JASBIR S. ARORA | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARORA%2C+JASBIR+S | Optimal Design Laboratory, College of Engineering, The University of Iowa, Iowa City, IA 52242, U.S.A. | U.S.A. | Iowa | The University of Iowa | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |
| 1016 | C. S. TSAI | NULL |  | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=TSAI%2C+C+S | Department of Civil Engineering, Feng Chia University, Taichung, Taiwan, Republic of China | Republic of China | Feng Chia University | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |

I tried to use xml potential for separate part of data( Note: *Add a single-cot in below cod manually*):

```
DECLARE @HtmlTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Html XML)

INSERT INTO @HtmlTbl(Html) VALUES('<div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
   <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A" class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a1" data-db-target-for="a1" aria-controls="a1" aria-haspopup="true" id="a1_Ctrl" role="button"><span>M. A. PRICE</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i></a>
   <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content" data-db-target-of="a1" aria-labelledby="a1_Ctrl" role="region" id="a1">
      <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen'+'s University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
      <a class="moreInfoLink" href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A">Search for more papers by this author</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
   <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G" class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a2" data-db-target-for="a2" aria-controls="a2" aria-haspopup="true" id="a2_Ctrl" role="button"><span>C. G. ARMSTRONG</span><i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i></a>
   <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content" data-db-target-of="a2" aria-labelledby="a2_Ctrl" role="region" id="a2">
      <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen'+'s University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
      <a class="moreInfoLink" href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G">Search for more papers by this author</a>
   </div>
</div>
COPY TO CLIPBOARD SELECT ALL')


--  SELECT
--    Html.query('//div')
--FROM @HtmlTbl 


SELECT
    C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM @HtmlTbl
CROSS APPLY Html.nodes('//div') AS T(C)
```

My destination table is Researcher and Company :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Researcher]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Full_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Tel] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Ostan] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [University] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Madrak] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Field] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [org] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](20) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Tel] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PostCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL
)
```

I need transfer data from `authors_html` column to Company and Researcher and cleaning data.

If you need connect to sample database use this connection :

```
IP: 185.141.105.232
user: wiley
pass: wiley
DB: wiley
```

Comment: XML sample is not well-formed. It is missing a root element. Is it a true shape of your XML?

Comment: You'll want to use a client procedure language for this to iterate through the records.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky SQLSERVER2019

Comment: @Amirhossein, so my proposed solution should work for you. It is for SQL Server 2016 onwards.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky yes, work well. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your starting point.

It is for SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @HtmlTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Html XML);
INSERT INTO @HtmlTbl(Html) VALUES('<div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
        <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A"
           class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a1"
           data-db-target-for="a1" aria-controls="a1" aria-haspopup="true"
           id="a1_Ctrl" role="button">
            <span>M. A. PRICE</span>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content"
             data-db-target-of="a1" aria-labelledby="a1_Ctrl" role="region"
             id="a1">
            <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen''s University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
            <a class="moreInfoLink"
               href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A">Search for more papers by this author</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-tabbed__tab-mobile accordion__closed">
        <a href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G"
           class="author-name accordion-tabbed__control" data-id="a2"
           data-db-target-for="a2" aria-controls="a2" aria-haspopup="true"
           id="a2_Ctrl" role="button">
            <span>C. G. ARMSTRONG</span>
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-section_arrow_d"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="author-info accordion-tabbed__content"
             data-db-target-of="a2" aria-labelledby="a2_Ctrl" role="region"
             id="a2">
            <p>Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen''s University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K.</p>
            <a class="moreInfoLink"
               href="http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G">Search for more papers by this author</a>
        </div>
    </div>');

-- INSERT INTO dbo.Researcher (Full_Name, [URL], [Address], University, Country) -- uncommemnt when you are ready
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(a/span/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Full_Name
    , c.value('(div/a/@href)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [URL]
    , c.value('(div/p/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Address]
    , JSON_VALUE(x,'$[1]') AS University
    , JSON_VALUE(x,'$[3]') AS Country
    -- continue with the rest
FROM @HtmlTbl
CROSS APPLY Html.nodes('/div') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('["' + REPLACE(c.value('(div/p/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),',','","') + '"]')) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+
| ID |    Full_Name    |                                     URL                                     |                                                     Address                                                     |             University             | Country |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | M. A. PRICE     | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=PRICE%2C+M+A     | Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K. |  The Queen's University of Belfast |  U.K.   |
|  1 | C. G. ARMSTRONG | http://185.141.105.238/action/doSearch?ContribAuthorStored=ARMSTRONG%2C+C+G | Department of Mechanical and Manufacturing Engineering, The Queen's University of Belfast, Belfast BT95AH, U.K. |  The Queen's University of Belfast |  U.K.   |
+----+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+
```